# How to get a Microsoft Exchange Client to work natively on elementary OS?

Tags: release-loki

I would like to migrate elementary OS to my work computer, but I would like to be able to connect my elementary OS to the microsoft mail exchange server.

Comment: Sorry response was slow! Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Office365 works out of the box with Mail.

Comment: Does you IT dept have OWA, Outook Web Access setup? This should work via a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I use elementaryOS on my work computer without any issues. For email I am using Thunderbird and simply connect to the Exchange server using imap, which works just fine right out of the box.

It gets better though if you add the Lightning plugin (for calendar) and the Exchange EWS Provider plugin. Thenb you can accept meeting requests and sync the calendar back to Exchange. LDAP also works for the company Exchange contacts. EWS isn't perfect, but stable enough for me. I do sometimes have an issue where I can not dismiss a reminder (this is very rare), but deleting the entry in the calendar will fix that.

A couple of additional things you may want to consider are Enigmail for signing/encrypting mail, and clamdrib + clamd for virus scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily. I'm not sure if the mail app does, it's worth trying first, and I'm sure it will soon of there are problems, but you should also be able to use Evolution, a mail app which I believe is available in the app store, below is a guide for getting set up on that.

https://www.linux.com/learn/use-evolution-connect-microsoft-exchange-linux

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird with the Exquilla add-on lets me read mail from Office365 exchange servers. I do not know the status of calendar support; I believe that it is *possible* but not trivial.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/

https://exquilla.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I talked to IT and they pretty much said that it's impossible to connect to our exchange server with linux. The workaround for me is that we are using office 365, which has a web client for almost every app including outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some food for thought i recently came across Hiri https://www.hiri.com/
which was specifically created for Linux to access o365 and exchange mailboxes.

Looks pretty cool but haven't had the opportunity to play with it yet.

It does have a cost which is very small when you take into account the user interface and work that's gone into the project - looks pretty good.

there's a 7 day trial available which i'm going to try out next week to see what its like.

hope the above helps.

""Cheers
G